# distribution of asymptotic random variables

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, random-variables, asymptotics

I have a series of continuous random variables $X_t$, $t \geq 0$, that satisfy the following two asymptotic relations:

- For any $n \geq 0$ and any $x$, let $t_n(x) \geq 0$ be the time corresponding to the $n$th local maximum of $X_t(x)$. Then there exists a sequence of random variables $Y_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_{t_n}(x)}{Y_n(x)} = 1$ for a.e. $x$.
- For a.e $x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{t_n(x)}{cn} = 1$.

Do we necessarily get that
$$\lim_{T \to \infty} P(\max_{1 \leq t \leq T} X_t(x) \leq T) = \lim_{N \to \infty} P(\max_{1 \leq n \leq N} Y_n(x) \leq cN)?$$
Do we need extra assumptions for an identity like this to be true?

Comment: Let's clarify some things. $X_t$ is a sequence of random variables, i.e. $t\in \mathbb N_0$? Or is $X_t$ a process with continuous trajectories?

Comment: The latter: It's a process with continuous trajectories $t \mapsto X_t(x), t \in \mathbb{R}_+$.